# Existence of a fundamental unit satisfying a Trace identity for cyclic cubic number fields?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a cyclic cubic number field.

1. If $w$ is a fundamental unit of negative norm, then must Trace$(w+1/w)=3$?

and a weaker question...

2. Is Trace$(w+1/w)=3$ necessarily true for *some* $w=uv^2$ where $u$ is a fundamental unit of negative norm and $v$ any unit?

**Remarks:** That $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is Galois is implied by the terminology "cyclic" and such a number field is totally real. By results of Armitage and Frohlich, every totally positive unit is a square if the class number of K is odd. If this helps, go ahead and assume odd class number.

Comment: The answer to 1st is negative, the fundamental units of splitting field of $x^3-21x-28$ gives counterexample, $\text{Tr}(w+1/w) = 66$. By the way, what is the significance of considering $w+1/w$?.

Comment: I have a lemma that states that if such a unit $w$ exists (as in the weak question), then I get the result I want. I'm just wondering if it's possible to relax some assumptions in my Lemma.

Comment: see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/312385/in-which-cyclic-cubic-number-fields-does-there-exist-this-type-of-unit